# Why EC2 instance is not accessible to others

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ec2

I deployed the Machine Learning classification model in AWS EC2 (UBUNTU)instance successfully. I am able to access the instance "http://ec2-18-191-31-0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com" and predictions are working fine only for few minutes. After that I or my colleagues are not able to access this. Getting an error "cannot connected to the server".

Security group that I crated as attached.[image]

Comment: Maybe you are running out of resources if your models are computational/memory intensive. So instance freezes. What is the instance type?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0dd9f0e7df0f0a138 (64-bit x86) / ami-0d2751e39abf67ea8 (64-bit Arm)

Comment: I mean instance type. t2.micro, c5.large, ...?

Comment: Instance type :- t2.micro

Answer (score 1):

`t2.micro` instances are not suitable for any long running calculations. They  are [burstable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html). This means that their performance can be **sustained only for short periods of time**, e.g., sudden, short lived spikes in CPU usage. On top of that they have only 1 GB of RAM which limits its usefulness in machine learning.

For calculations, you could consider [Compute optimized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compute-optimized-instances.html) or [Memory optimized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/memory-optimized-instances.html) instances. Obviously, these instance types are **not free**, but they are suited for calculations.

You can [change instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html) if you want and test with other, more power types. What you are describing indicates that your `t2.micro`  exhausts all its RAM and/or CPU burst credits after few minutes and it freezes.

You can use [CloudWatch Metrics for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html) to monitor your instances and observer its CPU utilization and other metrics which can help you determine what exactly is causing the backlog. You can also monitor RAM and disc usage but this requires [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) setup on the instance.